# LR(1) Automata: difference between items

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, automata, lr1

I have a doubt regarding the **LR(1)** automata construction:

Is the state with the kernel **[A->b., x] (state_1)** equivalent to the state with the kernel **[A->b.,x/y] (state_2)**?

Like, if I'm on the state **[A->.b, x]** and shift_b from this state, do I need to create state_1 if I already have state_2?

Hope it's clear.

Comment: What does this `x/y` mean in the question? Your question is unclear, I suggest you to show in a proper manner what you want to ask and don't go for any shortcuts.

Comment: Hey man. I'm not going for any shortcuts, this is the terminology of the dragon book (aho compiler book) and english is not my native language, so I'm sorry if it is not properly written. But x/y means that the lookahead associated with that item is either an x or an y